# Android spinner onitemselected add argument to create a function

Tags: android, spinner, recover

I would like to add an argument in 'onitemselected' for Spinner. The goal is to have a unique function instead of using 3 or 4 different functions with similar information.

Here is the code that I have with 'SelectedSpinnerSize' :

```
public void selectedSpinnerSize(int spinLayout){
  final Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(spinLayout);

  spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
  {
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)
     {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        selectedSize = map.get("Size").toString();
     }

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}

  });
}
```

And I have exactly the same code with 'selectedSpinnerWeight', 'selectedSpinnerLanguage', etc. The goal is to have a unique 'SelectedSpinnerInfo' and return the information ('selectedInfo' instead of 'selectedSize'). But as it's in a 'public void ...', I can't recover this value. So, what is the solution?

To be more clear, I would like something like this :

```
  public String selectedSpinnerInfo(int spinLayout)
  {
  final Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(spinLayout);

  spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
  {
  String selectedInfo;

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)
     {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        selectedInfo = map.get("Size").toString();
     }

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}

  });

  return selectedInfo;
```

}

Comment: If you just want to get the selected item, and not do anything with it, maybe `getSelectedView()` is a better way to do it? It isn't clear to me what you are wanting to do, maybe a bit more explaination would help...

Comment: OK, I'll try to give more explanation :

Comment: 1) The information into theses spinners come from MySQL
2) When I click on 1 of these spinners, I need to take the selected information to create information in another MySQL table. So the goal is only to take this value
3) I want to have something like
   public String selectedSpinnerInfo()
that return the selected info, but I can't because 'public void onitemselected' is another function that cannot return anything

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "SelectedSpinnerInfo" member variable in your activity or fragment and assign to it. Or if you need more than one you could have a map member variable keyed by the spinner id.